# How to deploy Nextjs13 in IIS

Tags: api, iis, next.js, next.js13

I build website with routes and api. But I have problem with deploying project in IIS.
I followed some tutorial to setup.

```js
const { createServer } = require("http");
const { parse } = require("url");
const next = require("next");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
    // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;

    if (pathname === "/a") {
      app.render(req, res, "/a", query);
    } else if (pathname === "/b") {
      app.render(req, res, "/b", query);
    } else {
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
    }
  }).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
`
```

This is server.js file.

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>    
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="myapp">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

   <iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" />

  </system.webServer>
    <location path="" overrideMode="Deny">
        <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>`
```

This is web.config file.

The above code is working but i cant access api routes. Can somehelp with this?

Comment: You can use IIS FRT to know what happens when accessing api route: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing.

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/#nextjs You might refer to the steps to configure HttpPlatformHandler for Next.js.